# Docker RUN Instruction with a Mounted Secret in Exec Form

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

What is the proper syntax for a `RUN` instruction in a `Dockerfile`, that requires mounting a secret, in *exec* form?

In other words, if a `Dockerfile` that looks something like:

```
FROM node:fermium-alpine

# . . .

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc yarn build:production

# . . .
```

how could the `RUN` instruction above be converted from *shell* form to *exec* form?  There doesn't seem to be an example in the official docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FROM node:fermium-alpine


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# . . .

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,dst=/usr/src/app/.npmrc ["/usr/local/bin/yarn", \
                                                          "build:production"]

# . . .
```

**Note**:

- The `--mount` flag is kept outside of the JSON array to its right
- The `dst=. . .` has been added to the `--mount` flag above to ensure that `.npmrc` is not only saved as a dotfile, but that it is saved in the `WORKDIR` so that `yarn` can use it during the `build`
- `RUN` instructions with the `--mount= . . .,dst=. . .` in *exec* form can get lengthy; use `\` to split long lines in a `Dockerfile` (taken from `Dockerfile` best practices [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run))
- Just to be on the safe side, since *shell* form is **not** being used here, the `yarn` executable was replaced with the absolute path `/usr/local/bin/yarn` for the `node:fermium-alpine` image